# What triggers thorns?

Tags: diablo-iii

The only other question about thorns is [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70454/what-counts-as-thorns-damage-for-the-barbarian-tough-as-nails-passive-abilit), which does not address several other issues about the mechanics on how it works.

In D3, if you dodge or block an attack does thorns still trigger?

Do any of the modifiers on Rare monster packs trigger thorns?

Does thorns replicate to your follower or from your follower's gear to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dodge any incoming attack, thorns will not trigger. This has been tested thoroughly and if you want to do any sort of thorns build, you will need to avoid dexterity and go for stamina instead. If you block, it does trigger since the enemy still has physical contact to you.

Thorns does also not replicate from your follower or to your follower, since only the person hit can trigger thorns.

Some reads:

http://threeorycrafting.blogspot.de/2013/04/mp5-thorns-barbarian.html

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/8197653222

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/7895009644